# Vim: How to show the error message when there is a syntax error?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have a C file (or ruby file) and I have a syntax error. When I save there is a bar that appears on the left, and an arrow pointing to the line where the syntax error is. I have the syntastic vim plugin installed so I don't know if that is a native feature or if it comes from the plugin.

Now my question is: **How can I see the error message from within vim?**

Comment: Then you make it hard. If you don't know what the plugin does, why did you install it?

Comment: I know that the plugin checks the syntax, but I'm not sure if it handles error messages. The README doesn't say anything about it too. Also, I read somewhere (after having installed the plugin) that vim handles the syntax checking itself, so I'm not sure what is causing the bar to appear on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has a built in ability to show you errors if you build a program using `:make` and has its own set of commands for working with errors produced by the compiler you are using.

HOWEVER, it seems that syntastic bypasses this functionality and preforms syntactic checks directly. The command you are looking for is probably `:Errors`. You should read the help for your plugin.

https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt

Comment: I just tried that, but even if there is an error `:cc` tells me there is none, which is odd...

Comment: How are you building the program? With `make`? I'm not familiar with the syntastic plugin.

Comment: I use `make` which uses `cc`. I also tried running `:make` from vim but it didn't find any errors either.

Comment: Try using `:Errors` if that doesn't work, you should probably read through the documentation for the plugin and figure out what's wrong. Post the answer here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `:Errors` was indeed the command I was looking for. I read briefly the plugin's documentation, but I was looking for `message` or `msg` that's why I didn't what I was looking for...